# Можно ли спользовать внешний SSD c USB 3.0 как основной жесткий?

Tags: ssd

Здравствуйте!

Есть внешний диск SSD. Подключен к ноутбуку серез USB 3.0(и диск и ноут поддерживают).Можно ли диск использовать как освноной жесткий. Т.е. На родном hdd стоит винда, а на ssd поставить linux/windows/mac, что бы всё это жило и не мешало друг другу.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ноутбук в биосе может выставить основным загрузчиком usb-устройство (есть у 90%+ моделей) - то да. Надо будет просто подключить ssd, подключить установочную флешку/вставить установочный диск, включить в биосе загрузку с установочного устройства, установить на ssd, включить в биосе загрузку с ssd.

Comment: Спасибо.Он будет быстрее или медленее работать, чем обычно подключенный hdd?Получается можно на 2 дисках держать убунту и хакинтошь, верно?

Comment: И ещё, они будут работать как полноценный компьютер?

Answer (score 1):

SSD по умолчанию быстрее будет, а так все упирается в пропускную способность USB порта.

> И ещё, они будут работать как полноценный компьютер?

Вполне.